# Set default input value Datetime.Now on create view MVC ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I set default value of input OpenDate is date and time of server.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="OpenDate" class="control-label">Ngày đăng ký</label>
   <input asp-for="OpenDate" class="form-control" />
   <span asp-validation-for="OpenDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the value of `mdoel.OpenDate = DateTime.Now;` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: Thank Stephen Muecke! Can you give me more detail. I'm beginner.

Comment: If I use @{Model.GiasuNgaydangky = DateTime.Now;} on view. An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You do it in the GET method, not the view - `YourModel model = new YourModel{ OpenDate = DateTime.Now }; return View(model);`

Comment: Thank Stephen Muecke!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your model:**
`[BindNever]`
`public System.DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }`

**In your Controller** (where you are posting the form)
`yourModel.OpenDate = DateTime.Now;`

**In your View:**
You can exclude the code that you have posted, because it will not be needed.

**Note:** I used "BindNever" because you can exclude this property from the model binding. It is a data that the system will get for you.

Comment: OP is creating a form control for it so it can be **edited** - adding `[NeverBind]` would not make sense