# ASP.NET Core HTML Helper is not setting Default Value for Date

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have a form where I want the date to default to today's date.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ThrDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="ThrDate" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" 
           type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ThrDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

My research would suggest that this would work, but the value is not actually passing through. Oh, and I still want the date picker to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another post gives us the answer:
[Set default input value Datetime.Now on create view MVC ASP.NET Core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249234/set-default-input-value-datetime-now-on-create-view-mvc-asp-net-core-2)

but it's in the comments, so I will detail here.

In the controller, in the GET, set the value of the model item, such like:

```
PostThr postThr = new PostThr { ThrDate = DateTime.Now };

return view(model);
```

once you do this, the value assigned in the controller passes to the view. No modification to the view is necessary.

Side note: I seem to now have trouble with the formatting of the value, but that's rich world problems, or another question.

Shout out to Stephen Muecke!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ThrDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="ThrDate" class="form-control" id="date_info" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ThrDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var time = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + time.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (time.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = time.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    $('#date_info').val(today);
})
</script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

And if you want use `datetimepicker`,you can use following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="ThrDate" class="control-label"></label>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input class="form-control datetimepicker-input" asp-for="ThrDate" type="text" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<script>
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({    
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        defaultDate: new Date(), 
    });
</script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Ok, I didnt get that. So, part 1 worked perfectly, and had the datepicker in there. But on this model, I need the time, which was not shown and didnt come up in the datepicker either. I realize that I didn't specify that I needed the time at al, so my bad. Part 2 didn't seem to work at all though.

Comment: For me, the second part works well, please make sure you and I use exactly the same code. You can copy it whole into your view, if it doesn't work, you can share your error message with me.

Comment: no error, just not the default specified. It just defaults to "01/01/0001 12:00" which is what I was getting without the code.